# MongoDB multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having issue with the whole multidimensional  updating Longs and Lats and I'm not sure how to allow update the current data with what the user submits. note: I have tried looking around and the examples still dont work

```
  Route.updateOne({ _id: Ids,  'Routes.Waypoints.Latitude': Lat, 'Routes.Waypoints:Longitude': Long }, { $set: {Routes:{Waypoints:{Latitude: NewLat, Longitude: NewLong }}}}, {  new: true },
       function (err, UpdatePoints) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        if (UpdatePoints) {
        console.log(UpdatePoints)
        }
      })
     
    })
```

Comment: The way that filter is written, that will match a document with that latitude in one waypoint and the longitude in a different waypoint.  Consider using "$elemMatch".

Comment: I have considered using "$elemMatch that has I did it while it was just Waypoints:[long and lat]. ```{_id:Ids, Routes:{Waypoints:{$elemMatch:{Latitude: Lat, Longitude: Long}}},{ $set: { 'Routes.Waypoints.$.Latitude': NewLat, 'Routes.Waypoints.$.Longitude': NewLong  } ```

Comment: I think last `})` is there in error

Comment: Sorry, thats my fault it was part of my app.get function